# How would one go about storing data after every filter over multiple queries from a database

Tags: javascript, mysql

Im using MySql as a database, and I have various types of data for animals.

How would I filter these animals multiple times, and keep the information stored for later use to be inserted in an element later on? I dont even know where to start with this, but hopefully I explained it to the best of my ability.

Would they be stored in a variable everytime I query it, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can query once and store it in a variable. Use it as you see fit. 
An example :

```
const animals = [
    {
        "name": "cat",
        "size": "small",
        "weight": 5
    },
    {
        "name": "dog",
        "size": "small",
        "weight": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "lion",
        "size": "medium",
        "weight": 150
    },
    {
        "name": "elephant",
        "size": "big",
        "weight": 5000
    }
];

let filterArray = animals.filter((animal) => {return animal.size === 'small'});
console.log(filterArray);
```

Let us say the array of objects is what you get from the database. You store it and when you need, sort it with what you want as criteria.

If anyone has any other suggestions, please mention.

Comment: Thanks dude. I suck at logic, but a little more keeps me "LearningEveryday"

Comment: @KawaiiSlave please accept the answer if this answers your question!